# A free host (game) server for a mobile application

Tags: gratis, web-services, game, hosted, game-development

Recently I developed a game and distributed it via play store.

Now I am thinking of providing "High score rank competition system", which enables users to see other's high score and see theirselves' rank.

Is there any free server hosting service that runs 24 hours everyday, and enables socket communication?

(I mean I do not have any html page to show through web browsers, but the server should be accessible using socket communication, etc..)

To elaborate, I may have to show some code..

Client side:

```
String hostName = "www.example.com";
int portNumber = 12345;
try 
{
    Socket socket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    out.write(QUERY_HIGHEST_SCORE_USER_INFO);
    ArrayList<RankInfo> infos= new ObjectInputStream(in).readObject();
...

}
```

Sorry for a bit vague question ;)

Comment: Would any remote database be OK? You need both read and write, correct? How much traffic? Have you thought about authentication?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Yeah, I need both read and write. I think there will be relatively low traffic. Authentication? Sorry but no :( I am completely new to this era.